# What does Mark Twain mean by "keep hotel"?

Tags: meaning, mark-twain

The protagonist in *A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court* uses this phrase:

> But that should be nothing to his discredit; the man that can do THIS kind of miracle knows enough to keep hotel.

This led me to find another passage, this time in Twain's *Notebooks*, containing the phrase:

> It is an art apart. Saint Francis of Assisi said, "All saints can do miracles, but few of them can keep hotel."

I still don't know what to make of it, though.

Comment: To "keep hotel" means to manage a hotel, or "run" a hotel. Similar to "keep house."

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Want to post that as an answer? It would do fine as one, if you add a reference (such as [this](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+house) for example).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about the ordinary meaning of an expression and should be migrated to [elu.se].

Comment: @Chappo I'm voting to leave open because questions about the meaning in context of passages in literature have always been on-topic here. This one *seems* answerable simply with a little knowledge of English idiom, but OTOH a little Googling suggests that Mark Twain is the only person to have used the phrase "keep hotel".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary has this definition for **to keep**:

> To carry on and manage, to conduct as one's own (an establishment or business, a school, shop, etc.).

This sense of the verb well predates Twain, dating back to [Middle English](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED24173/track?counter=1&search_id=912222).

Two common expressions of this form are [**to keep house**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+house) and [**to keep (a) shop**](https://books.google.com/books?id=LAKQCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq="keep+a+shop".).

Therefore "keep hotel" simply means **run a hotel**.